# FILTER row level records based on config table entry and user sessions in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to do below

I have created one config table like below

[image]

Now I want to create a view using this config table and the with specific user who is selecting this view, the user should see only those value for which user is allowed as per config table.

```
SELECT * FROM MAINTABLE INNER JOIN CONFIG_ACCESS 
ON MAINTABLE.ALLOWED_EMPID = CONFIG_ACCESS.ALLOWED_EMPID 
AND MAINTABLE.ALLOWED_DEPTID= CONFIG_ACCESS.ALLOWED_DEPTID
AND MAINTABLE.ALLOWED_COUNTRY= CONFIG_ACCESS.ALLOWED_COUNTRY
```

Here with this "AND", nothing returns.

Ideally, it should dynamically set the INNER JOIN condition based on user logged in.

Like if user : ab@gmail.com is logged into snowflake , for him the join would be with "ALLOWED_EMPID".

if the user is cd@gmail.com , for him the join would be with "ALLOWED_DEPTID".

I am trying to code as below

```
SET USERID=CURRENT_USER();
--SELECT $USERID
SET JOIN_COL = 
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN ALLOWED_EMPID <> 'NA' THEN 'ALLOWED_EMPID'
    WHEN ALLOWED_DEPTID <> 'NA' THEN 'ALLOWED_DEPTID'
    WHEN ALLOWED_COUNTRY <> 'NA' THEN 'ALLOWED_COUNTRY'
END 
FROM CONFIG_ACCESS AS CONFIG_ACCESS WHERE CONFIG_ACCESS.USERID = $USERID);

--SELECT $JOIN_COL -- DEPT01

SELECT distinct T0.DEPT01 FROM  MAINTABLE  AS T0 
inner join CONFIG_ACCESS AS T1 ON T0.DEPT01 = T1.$JOIN_COL
```

But it errors out

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 54 unexpected 'ON'.
```

Is there a way to dynamically do this?

Comment: Hi - it looks like you are trying to achieve ROW based access control i.e. limit which rows a user can see in a table, rather than limit whether a user can query a table at all. RBAC is commonly used to mean ROLE based access control, hence my confusion. Can you confirm that you are trying to implement ROW based access control? If you are, have you read Snowflake's documentation on the subject, which has lots of examples: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-row-intro.html

Comment: Yes, i am trying to limit the rows from a view based on the condition provided in config table. I have gone through the documentation. But here my requirement is based on user the filter will change, it can be EMPID or DEPTID or COUNTRY. Hence dynamically the join should take place

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [Using Secure Views with Snowflake Access Control](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-secure.html#using-secure-views-with-snowflake-access-control)